# Is there any point where While loop is better than For loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I've read an article in the [Effective Java](http://books.google.ru/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=prefer+for+loops+to+while+effective+java&source=bl&ots=yYJhOkpZO0&sig=Rck5pf9kZY58RqHXnXoHDIhqYeo&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=CCnRUfLNMqmG4ASb44CIAQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) about preferring `For` loops to `While` loops.
`For` loops have a lot of advantages over `While` loops. But is there any disadvantages in preferring `For` to `While`?

Comment: what is the advantage of the `for` loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java for loop vs. while loop. Performance difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165457/java-for-loop-vs-while-loop-performance-difference)

Comment: `for` loops and `while` loops are the same.

Comment: It's ok that performance is the same. Maybe there aresome other downsides of a `for` loop?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot this is not a duplicate as it does not focus on performance. It is about what is written in a book and why. Read my answer as there is a slight difference in variable visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no disadvantage. But for the below case using while loop is more conventional

```
bool condition = false;
while(!condition)
{

}
```

Comment: Seems like there is really no disadvantages since there are only one not-offtopic answer.

Answer (score 2):

The **Item 45** (in 2nd Edition of the book) talks about the scope of variables. To minimize the scope of a local variable the `while` loop has a disadvantage:

```
boolean condition = false;
while (!condition) {
    // do stuff
}
// Here the variable condition still exists
```

The `for` loop can limit the visibility

```
for (boolean condition = false; !condition;) {
    // do stuff
}
// Here the variable condition is out of scope and can be garbage collected
```

This is all that is preferable according to the book.

Answer (score 1):

For loop is widly used and has more advantages over while loop but ther are some cases when while loop is perferable 
Case 1. 
when you are playing on booleans. In that case if you are using for loop you explicity define a variable to check or you creat for loop with only condition value in taht case while loop is preferrable

```
Boolean condition = false;
while(!condition)
{
    condition = doSomething();
}
```

is preferrable then use of

```
 Boolean condition = false;
 for(;condition;)
 {
     condition = doSomething();
 }
```

case 2. 
for better visibilty and understanding. When you are working on iterators it is better to use while loop it gives to more clear view of code .

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String string = (String) iterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of a for loop over a while loop is readability. A For loop is a lot cleaner and a lot nicer to look at. It's also much easier to get stuck in an infinite loop with a while loop. I would say that I agree with your knowledge that if you can use a for loop, you should, so as long as you stick to that, your programming experiences will be much more enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is JIT optimisations for for loops are easier so more likely to be applied i.e. if we know the number of times a loop will execute then we can unroll it.

Some discussions of loop optimisations and JIT

- [How the JIT optimizes code](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142j9%2Fhtml%2Fhowjitopt.html)
- [JVM performance optimisation](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2012/120905-jvm-performance-optimization-compilers.html?page=6)
  -