# How expensive are for and while loops?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

The question is asking for a comparison between costs of `for` and `while` loops, relative to the cost of `if` statements.

Say an if statement has a relative cost of 1, what's the relative cost of for and while loops?

Assume that a single boolean value is being passed onto the `while` loop and `if` statement when comparing and the `while` is allowed to iterate X times. Assume that the `for` also iterates X number times.

Comment: [Microoptimizations are evil](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165457/java-for-loop-vs-while-loop-performance-difference

Comment: You can time it yourself to see .. also

Comment: What does it mean to have a "single boolean" in a for loop?

Comment: How is this getting 8 downvotes? It's not even a bad question..

Comment: @ThePixelPony - it doesn't show a ton of effort though. research and code and such silly stuff

Comment: @Paul Just a single `boolean` variable. Example: boolean yes = true; while(yes) etc

Comment: It's a dreadful question. Please explain why you're asking. A for-loop isn't obviously comparable to a if statement, for a start

Comment: And what happens to that single boolean value in the loop? If not modified, they're all basically if statements. If modified, the if statement executes once, the while /for potentially many times (obviously, which is why it really isn't clear what you're actually asking)

Comment: @Coffee I suppose but it's a pretty simple question; there isn't really much else that I could have added to be honest.

Comment: @Paul, well, it's asking to compare a while and for loop, relative to an if statement.

Comment: But they're not comparable! An if statement executes at most once, a for/while loop potentially many times.

Comment: @Paul Looks like I didn't phrase this too well. I was referring to the cost. *Say an `if` statement has a relative cost of 1, what's the relative cost of `for` and `while` loops?* The current answer covers this.

Comment: Rephrase it. It'll get more publicity.

Comment: time complexity is n of loops so compare that to if statements

Comment: @laiello I have tried to rephrase my quesiton to make it more clear.

Comment: Good, then I've answered it right :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of performance, `if` statements are usually of O(1) complexity, where as `for` and `while` loops are usually O(n), where n is the amount of loops it takes depending on what the conditions are. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    // Some statements
}
```

Would be O(100), because it is looped through 100 times. It does not matter how many statements are inside the `for` loop, **unless** there are additional loops inside the initial loop. Then you get to O(n^2) complexity, which is quadratic and thus highly inefficient.

However, do not let this scare you. Loops exist for a reason, and they are necessary in many programs.

Comment: @laiello - Nah .. I know. just too brief is all. maybe we judge quickly

Comment: also if you need to loop 100 times it would certainly be more clean then 100 if statements. also you will barely notice these time differences with todays computers unless you are doing something very intensive.

Comment: I agree, but I implore you to go to an algorithms professor and say to him "Loop complexity does not matter". Maybe not for overall programs, but in Computer Science, it is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are language constructs. You can write a `while` loop to do the same thing as a `for` loop and vice versa.

> Say an if statement has a relative cost of 1, what's the relative cost of for and while loops?

`for` loops and `while` loops also check a condition. In that sense, they also have a cost of `1`. The point is that there is typically something in the loop that will affect that condition.

Consider this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    }

    System.out.println("");

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

The bytecode generated is

```
    // start for
     0: iconst_0
     1: istore_1
     2: iload_1
     3: bipush        10
     5: if_icmpge     14
     8: iinc          1, 1
    11: goto          2
    // end for
    14: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    17: ldc           #3                  // String
    19: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    // start while
    22: iconst_0
    23: istore_1
    24: iload_1
    25: bipush        10
    27: if_icmpge     36
    30: iinc          1, 1
    33: goto          24
    36: return
    // end while
```

You'll notice both loops do the exact same thing and generate the exact same bytecode.